# Send many emails at once by Thunderbird by c#

Tags: c#, email, command-line, thunderbird

I am sending emails to many people by Thunderbird by c#. I do it with loop. My problem is that when I run my application - for any email I send a new Thunderbird window is openning, and then I need to press "send" and so it is send. It is very inconvenient. How can I send all the emails at once?

My code:

```
string strCommand;
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
   strCommand = " -compose to=" + (char)34 + astrRecip[i] + (char)34 + ",";
   strCommand += "body=" + (char)34 + strMessage[i] + (char)34 + ",";
   strCommand += "subject=" + (char)34 + strSubject + (char)34 + ",";
   strCommand += "attachment=" + (char)34 + strAttachment[i] + (char)34;
   Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird", strCommand);
}
```

I think that because I write "-compose" to every email so it is open a new window, maybe if I write one command-line it will be OK. I tried, but with no success.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Thunderbird to send your mail vs. using SMTP?  Also, your code won't work on any 64-bit OS because Thunderbird will install to C:\Program Files (x86)\...

Comment: Why do you send it with Thynderbird instead of sending it directly with C# and System.Net.Mail namespace?

Comment: I use Thunderbird because of many reasons there is no place to write them all here. One of them is because my boss wants it.

Comment: @Joe, my code is work, my question is how to do it better.

Comment: @Chanipoz: If your boss makes non-sense requirements it is your duty to inform him about his requirement being non-sense. Maybe he doesn't know better.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, i WROTE that I have MANY reasons, not one.

Comment: @Chanipoz: I know that you wrote that. I can't believe that even one of them makes sense if you want to send bulk mail!

Comment: @Chanipoz I am detecting a certain attitude against the other commenters. You won't get much help with an attitude like that. They are only trying to assist you

Comment: @ Default, You are right, but instead of get assist - an answer to my question, I get comments how to do it else, and when I'm writing that I must do it this way, I'm still get the same comments.

Comment: that's because the typical reasoning of a programmer is do it the lazy way - and doing it via `SmtpClient` as Daniel suggests seems **much** easier then doing it through a third-party program. Since they do not understand the requirement of why that program should be used, other solutions, that seem simpler, will be proposed. My reaction to your statement that "no place to write them here" is simply that there are no good reasons to use it. Thus, other solutions will be proposed. When you say that "your boss wants it", that is a requirement that can be changed to reach a more simple solution.

Comment: Your question basically says *"I have found a way to reach something via this very complicated way, but there is one small thing that is not working. How do I resolve this small thing?"* - This will generate answers that says *"Don't use that complicated way. Use this simple way instead"*. So.. you need to give your reason as to why you are using the complicated way.

Answer (score 6):

You really should use the [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class from the .NET framework.

Comment: Generally yes, one exception would be that I want to use my preconfigured crypto without the overhead of setting it up again in code (esp for gpg but even s/mime if your certs are only in TBs cert store so far).

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple email addresses in one compose argument, as an example shows in [Command line arguments - Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29).

So, instead of starting the process in each loop, join all the email addresses and start one process afterwards. This is simple using [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350%28VS.100%29.aspx).

```
string strCommand;
strCommand = " -compose to=" + (char)34 + string.Join(",", astrRecip) + (char)34 + ",";
strCommand += "body=" + (char)34 + strMessage[i] + (char)34 + ",";
strCommand += "subject=" + (char)34 + strSubject + (char)34 + ",";
strCommand += "attachment=" + (char)34 + strAttachment[i] + (char)34;
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird", strCommand);
```

---

Edit: note that you can escape the " if you want using \". So instead of using `(char)34` you can type

```
strCommand = " -compose to=\"" + string.Join(",", astrRecip) + "\",";
```

and, by using string format, this can be even easier to read.

```
strCommand = string.Format("-compose to=\"{0}\",", string.Join(",", astrRecip));
```

since you seperate the string from it's arguments.

Comment: I just noticed you use an array for body and subject as well. Do they change or are they the same? If they differ, this solution will not be that effective.. :-/

Comment: @Chanipoz: Oh I see. Then you don't have a choice but to either open one window per user, or use the solution suggested by Daniel. Perhaps a small adjustment can be to wait for the current process to end, using Process.WaitFor. At least then you don't have 100 windows that open at once, but rather one at a time.